# Pragma omp parallel overhead

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a problem with a `#pragma omp parallel` section in my code.
I hava program which should sort a given array of integers with quicksort using multiple threads. For this in every step every thread gets assigned a portion of the array, partitions it and returns how many elements are smaller than a given global pivot. The code executes without errors, but the more threads I tell omp to use, the slower it executes. I added logging for the execution times and it seems like a huge part of the program is spent on overhead for OpenMP. The overhead seems to be consistent, so the speed difference is proportional to the size of the array to sort.

Here is the code which is executed in parallel:

```
void create_count_elems_lower(int lower, int upper, int global_pivot_position, int *block_sizes, int *data,
                              int *count_elems_lower) {
    assert(lower >= 0);
    times_function_called++;
    int pivot = data[global_pivot_position];
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    double wait_start = 0;
    double wait_time = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads(); ++i) {
        double start_thread = omp_get_wtime();
        int lower_p = lower;
        lower_p += i == 0 ? 0 : block_sizes[i - 1] * i;
        count_elems_lower[i] = partition_fixed_pivot(lower_p, lower_p + block_sizes[i], pivot, data) -
                               lower_p; // - lower_p since it needs to be relative
        assert(count_elems_lower[i] >= 0);
        double end_thread = omp_get_wtime();
        double time_spent = end_thread - start_thread;
        time_spent_per_thread_sum += time_spent;
        if (max_time_spent_per_thread[i] < time_spent) {
            max_time_spent_per_thread[i] = time_spent;
        }
        if (wait_start == 0) {
            wait_start = end_thread;
        } else {
            double time_waiting = end_thread - wait_start;
            if (time_waiting > wait_time) {
                wait_time = time_waiting;
            }
        }
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    time_spent_in_function += end - start;
    time_spent_idling += wait_time;
}
```

And here the testing function:

```
printf("Num threads: %d\n", num_threads);
double start = omp_get_wtime();
test_sort_big();
double end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("total: %f\n", end - start);
printf("times function called: %f\n", times_function_called);
printf("time spent in create_count_elems_lower: %f\n", time_spent_in_function);
printf("time spent per thread approx: %f\n", time_spent_per_thread_sum / num_threads);
printf("time spent idling: %f\n", time_spent_idling);
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
    printf("max time spent by thread %d: %f \t", i, max_time_spent_per_thread[i]);
}
```

The program gets compiled and linked with:

```
gcc      -fopenmp  -O3  -c -o tests/tests.o tests/tests.c
gcc      -fopenmp  -o build_test tests/tests.o array_utils.o datagenerator.o quicksort.o
```

And the results are:

```
Num threads: 1
Testing sorting of 10000000 Elements
total: 9.204632
times function called: 10000000.000000
time spent in create_count_elems_lower: 5.914602
time spent per thread approx: 1.610363
time spent idling: 0.000000
max time spent by thread 0: 0.041889 


Num threads: 4
Testing sorting of 10000000 Elements
total: 16.955334
times function called: 10000000.000000
time spent in create_count_elems_lower: 12.598185
time spent per thread approx: 0.874607
time spent idling: 2.130419
max time spent by thread 0: 0.016055    max time spent by thread 1: 0.013543    max time spent by thread 2: 0.013532    max time spent by thread 3: 0.018599
```

I run Fedora 27 64 bit with an Intel® Core™ i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8

**Edit:**
As it turned out the overhead was the problem, since the method gets called a lot of times with only one thread, changing the algorithm to a simple sort when only one thread is available improved the runtime a lot.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I updated it to use a parallel for, but it basically does the same as before, since the marked section gets executed in parallel

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I can see the system using 4 threads to the full extent, what do they do then?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark furthermore I aim to parallelise the partitioning here, most of the questions on SO focus on parallising the sorting of the sub arrays

Comment: Good luck with that, you're way beyond my capabilities to help further.